# arabic numbers with lualatex

Tags: arabluatex

How to change hindi numbers to arabic numbers  in  arabluatex ?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{amiri}

\begin{document}

Inside :

\begin{arab}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
\end{arab}

Now \arb{3 kutubiN}

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

 \arb{ kutubiN} 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\LR{0}`,  `\LR{1}`, `\LR{2}`, ...

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but what  if I want that all numbers appear  automatically ?

Comment: As said by @SalimBou `\LR{<num>}` is the way to go.  But I will add an option for setting the numbers in the next release of `arabluatex`.

Comment: That's what I expected. Thank you.